# Need some help in fixing this error related to S3 document upload

Tags: apex, aws, amazon-s3

I am trying to upload documents into S3 and receiving status as **Forbidden**. Here is the error I am receiving

> The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your key and signing method.

Below is the code which I am using.

```
    tring binaryPDF = 's3test';
    String key = '*****';
    String secret = '###';
    String docName = 'PublicAccess';
    String contentType = 'pdf';
    String method='PUT';
    String bucketname='BucketName';
    String formattedDateString = Datetime.now().format('EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z','UTC');
    String filename;
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    Http http = new Http();
    filename = 'folder/' + docName.replace(' ', '+') + '.pdf';   
    req.setHeader('ACL', 'public-read');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', contentType);
    req.setMethod(method);
    req.setHeader('Host','s3.amazonaws.com');  //path style
    req.setEndpoint('https://s3.amazonaws.com' + '/'+ bucketname + '/' + filename);
   req.setHeader('Date', formattedDateString);

    String stringToSign = method+'\n\n'+contentType+'\n'+formattedDateString+'\n\n\nx-amz-acl: public-read\n\n\n/'+bucketname+'/'+filename;
    Blob mac = Crypto.generateMac('HMACSHA1', blob.valueof(stringToSign),blob.valueof(secret));
    String sig = EncodingUtil.base64Encode(mac);
    String auth = 'AWS' + ' ' + key + ':' + sig;

    req.setHeader('Authorization',auth);

        Blob pdfBlob = EncodingUtil.base64Decode(binaryPDF);
        req.setBodyAsBlob(pdfBlob);
        req.setHeader('Content-Length', string.valueOf(binaryPDF.length()));

            HTTPResponse res = http.send(req);
```

Comment: Compare your code against [mine](https://gist.github.com/brianmfear/db444a87f35a5a6348784a683b4cbd18). I don't see anything immediately obvious, but maybe this will help you.

Comment: If I remove public access (x-amz-acl: public-read) from signature it is returning success but I want the document to be publicly available.

Comment: Oh, in your header you set ACL, but in the string you set x-amz-acl. They should match.

Comment: @sfdcfox that is the correct answer.  Please post it as an answer.

Comment: I tried modifying the header to x-amz-acl from ACL but still returning the same error.

Comment: Even tried ACL in both places and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

The headers you specify should match. In your signature, you used "x-amz-acl," but the header was simply "ACL." Make sure that you're setting the correct header names.